# Compare data from two files and update the 2nd file in Shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression

I need to compare data from two files and based on the condition I need to update the 2nd file in Shell.

I have two set of files.

The first file contains data as

```
NUMBER,ID
748378,9508
473738,7892
473832,7839
```

The 2nd file contains data as

```
pk,Name,Number,Code
1,Michael,748378,6373
2,Rachael,747477,7473
```

What I wanted to do is to update 2nd file as if pk is not equal to 1 in 2nd file and Number in 1st file is equal to Number in 2nd file then set Code in file 2 = ID from file 1.

I am having troubles while working on this logic in shell.

Comment: How many lines do the files contain? The problem is not that difficult, but the solution depends on the number of records (lines in the files) and the available memory.

Comment: The file contains around 2K records

Comment: The sentence stating your needs isn't clear, please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 1):

MS Excel `vlookup` would be a quick/easy solution for this.

If Excel isn't an option for you, I'd do the amalgamation of awk/sed/shell:

`awk -F, '{if ($1 != 1 && $1 ~ /[0-9]+/) {print "sed -i \x27s#" $3 ",[0-9]*#" $3 "," $4 "#\x27 file1.txt"}}' file2.txt | bash`

Like Mathias mentioned and if I understood the original intent correctly:

> Only apply the fix to file1 if the pk in file2 isn't 1.

in which case, you have no match since "pk1 number748378" in file2 is the only match found in file1 and you're excluding the fix when pk is 1.

In my provided one-liner, change `if ($1 != 1` to `if ($1 != 2` to see the result.

Explanation for the awk/sed/bash amalgamation:

`awk -F,` -F says use whatever follows as the delimiter, in this case, use `,`

`if ($1 != 1 && $1 ~ /[0-9]+/)` if field 1`$1` doesn't equal to 1 AND if field 1 is a number, apply the followed awk procedure. `$1 ~ /reg_exp/` is the `awk` regular expression syntax.

`print "sed -i \x27s#" $3 ",[0-9]*#" $3 "," $4 "#\x27 file1.txt"` is using `awk` to print a `sed` command to apply the fix to file1.txt.    `$3` is the NUMBER is and `$4` is the CODE in file2.txt. `\x27` is the HEX code for `awk` to print `'`.

In essence, use `awk` to look up field 3 and 4 in file2 and use `sed` to generate the command to replace the number in file1 with results provided from `awk`, then run the resulting `sed` command through `bash` (or any other shell you have)

Comment: Hi! I wanted to update the 2nd file not the 1st file

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the script you want:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR {
        map[$1] = $2
        next
    }
    ($1 != 1) && ($3 in map) {
        $4 = map[$3]
    }
    { print }
' file1 file2
```

but it doesn't look like any lines in your sample input match the criteria you specified so none would get changed so there's no way to test it given what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

The following Perl script can do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = shift;

my %ids_by_number;

if ($file1 && open(my $f1, "<", $file1)) {
  my ($number,$id) = split(/,/,<$f1>);
  while (<$f1>) {
    my ($number,$id) = split(/,/);
    $ids_by_number{$number} = $id;
  }
}
else {
  print "please provide file1 on the command line\n";
  exit 1;
}

while (<>) {
  my ($ok,$name,$number,$code) = split(/,/);
  if ("1" ne $ok && exists($ids_by_number{$number})) {
    print join(",",$ok,$name,$number,$ids_by_number{$number}),"\n";
  }
  else {
    print $_;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately your example contains no line that would match the condition as I understand it. I tested it therefore against the following file:

```
pk,Name,Number,Code
1,Michael,748378,6373
2,Rachael,747477,7473
3,Raffael,473738,1234
```

You can call the script either with both filenames in the command line:

```
$ ./update file1 file2
```

Or you feed file2 to STDIN:

```
$ ./update file1 file2
```

Both invocations result in the following output on STDOUT:

```
pk,Name,Number,Code
1,Michael,748378,6373
2,Rachael,747477,7473
3,Raffael,473738,7892
```

Comment: I really appreciate the solution but I am looking to implement the logic in shell

Comment: @Mr.Underscore If you want to implement it in shell then a) that would be a terrible idea and b) why did you tag it with awk and sed (2 other tools that also are not shell)? Maybe what you meant to says is you want to do it using mandatory POSIX tools (which would include awk and sed but exclude perl)?

Comment: @Mr.Underscore Then I would recommend the solution from Ed Morton, it gives the same output as mine.